# Is it possible to open two sockets on server side

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am building an app using nodeJS along with socket io . 
I have a server.js file in which i did the following :

```js
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("a user is connected");
});
```

Also i have another file "api.js" in which i have the following function :

```js
filter.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error){  
    var newblock = new Block(web3.eth.getBlock(result));

    newblock.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) return handleError(err);
                  // saved!
    })
  }
});
```

Im trying to send the object "newblock" (which is changing constantly) from the file api.js to server.js with socket io . I tried doing " socket.emit('fromApi_toserver',newblock)" in api.js but it's not working... Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need to open a different socket? You can use the the same `io` instance and do `io.emit('fromApi_toserver', 'hello world')` in your apijs file and listen in your server js file `io.on('fromApi_toserver', function (msg){.....})`

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be several issues here.

First, if you want to send to all connected clients, then you would use `io.emit()`, not `socket.emit()`.

Second, since `io` is defined in your `app.js` file, if you want access to it in your `api.js` file, then you need to specifically make it available to that file.  There are a number of ways to do that, but the most common is to pass it to that file with a module constructor when the `api.js` module is loaded.  Here's a way to do that:

app.js

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("a user is connected");
});

// pass io variable to app.js when loaded
require('api.js')(io);
```

api.js

```
// define module constructor
let io;
modules.exports = function(socketio) {
    // save io instance for later use
    io = socketio;
}

filter.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error){  
    var newblock = new Block(web3.eth.getBlock(result));

    newblock.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // send JSON stringified version of newblock to all connected clients
        io.emit(newblock);
    });
  }
});
```

Third, you can't send live objects to clients.  Data for socket.io is serialized into JSON strings before sending to clients and the client-side socket.io will then deserialize the JSON back into an object.  But, it will just be a plain object on the client end, not any specific object type.  If you need the data to be a specific object type (such as a client-side Block object), then you must take the data you receive and use it to create your own new client-side Block object.

Fourth, your questions asked about a second socket, but you don't need another socket.  You can use the `io` instance to send to all currently connected clients with `io.emit()`.

Comment: @Sarah - Did this answer your question?